# error in observable with HttpResponse in service

Tags: javascript, typescript, rxjs, observable

I have a service and I am using the HttpClient. But I get an error in the constructor of the observable.

```
getDossierEntryFileData( entryID: number ): Observable<HttpResponse<Blob>> {
 return this.http.get<HttpResponse<Blob>>( '/api/patient/{patientUUID}/DossierEntry/' + entryID + '/fileData', 'pdf', true);
}
```

But I get this error:

```
Expected 1-2 arguments, but got 3.ts(2554)
```

on the property true

So this is the old method:

```
 getDossierEntryFileData( entryID: number ): Observable<HttpResponse<Blob>> {
    return this.get( '/api/patient/{patientUUID}/DossierEntry/' + entryID + '/fileData', 'pdf', true );
  }
```

So I want to refactor that.

and this is the old get method:

```
 get( route: string, responseType: RespType = 'json', fullResponse: boolean = false, params = null): Observable<any> {
    return this.invoke( 'GET', route, null, responseType, fullResponse, true, params);
  }
```

So this are the old methods:

```
invoke(
    method: 'GET' | 'POST' | 'PUT' | 'DELETE',
    route: string,
    body?: any,
    responseType: RespType = 'json', // PDF gets translated to array buffer and the application/pdf accept header
    fullResponse: boolean  = false,
    needsAuthenticatedUser = true,
    params: HttpParams = null
  ): Observable<any> {
    const user$ = this.authService.loginStatus()
                      .pipe( take( 1 ) );

    return user$.pipe(
      map( user => {
        let parsedRoute = route;
        if ( needsAuthenticatedUser ) {
          if ( !user ) {
            throw Error( 'Tried to call api that requires login without a user profile present' );
          } else {
            parsedRoute = parsedRoute.replace('{userId}', user.profile.sub);
            parsedRoute = parsedRoute.replace('{patientUUID}', user.profile.participant);
          }
        }
        return environment.ApiOrigin + parsedRoute;
      } ),
      switchMap( url => {
        const accessToken = this.authService.getAccessToken();

        const headers = {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          'Accept'      : HealthAPIService._responseTypes[ responseType ].mime
        };

        if ( !!accessToken ) {
          headers[ 'Authorization' ] = `Bearer  ${accessToken}`;
        }

        const options = {
          body        : body,
          responseType: HealthAPIService._responseTypes[ responseType ].decode as
            | 'json'
            | 'text'
            | 'arraybuffer',
          headers     : new HttpHeaders( headers )
        };
        if ( fullResponse ) {
          options[ 'observe' ] = 'response';
        }
        if (params !== null) {
          options['params'] = params;
        }

        return this.http.request( method, url, options )
                   .pipe( catchError(err => this.handleError(err)) );
      } )
    );
  }

  get( route: string, responseType: RespType = 'json', fullResponse: boolean = false, params = null): Observable<any> {
    return this.invoke( 'GET', route, null, responseType, fullResponse, true, params);
  }

  post( route: string, body: any, responseType: RespType = 'json' ): Observable<any> {
    return this.invoke( 'POST', route, body, responseType );
  }

  put( route: string, body: any, responseType: RespType = 'json' ): Observable<any> {
    return this.invoke( 'PUT', route, body, responseType );
  }

  delete( route: string, responseType: RespType = 'json' ): Observable<any> {
    return this.invoke( 'DELETE', route, null, responseType );
  }

  private handleError( error: any ): Observable<any> {
    if ( error.status && error.status === 401 ) {
      console.error( 'Authorization failed, trying to login.' );
      this.authService.requestLogin();
    }
    console.dir( error );
    if ('error' in error) {
      // This is necessary to allow measurement-form-component
      // handleFormErrors to give correct feedback.
      return observableThrowError(error);
    }
    return observableThrowError( error.message || error );
  }
```

But Now I am bussy with rewriting them

But I have a other method like this:

```
getDossierEntry( type: String = '' ): Observable<DossierEntry[]> {
  const entryType = type === '' ? 'all' : 'type/' + type;
  return this.http.get<DossierEntry[]>('/api/patient/{patientUUID}/DossierEntry/' + entryType );
}
```

But if I call this method it doesnt work.

But If I do this:

```
getDossierEntry( type: String = '' ): Observable<Array<DossierEntry>> {
    const entryType = type === '' ? 'all' : 'type/' + type;
    return this.get( '/api/patient/{patientUUID}/DossierEntry/' + entryType );
  }
```

Then it will work. So with the old way

s this work:

```
  this.healthAPIService.getDossierEntry('correspondence').subscribe(result => {
      this.handleCorrespondenceLoad(result), (this.correspondenceLoaded = true);
      console.log(result);

    }, msg => (this.message = this.errorMessageConnection));
  }
```

But if I do This:

```
   this.documentCorrespondeceService.getDossierEntry('correspondence').subscribe(result => {
      this.handleCorrespondenceLoad(result), (this.correspondenceLoaded = true);
      console.log(result);

    }, msg => (this.message = this.errorMessageConnection));
  }
```

Then it doesnt work

I get now an:

```
GET http://localhost:4200/api/patient/%7BpatientUUID%7D/DossierEntry/type/physical 404 (Not Found)
scheduleTask @ zone.js:3372
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.scheduleTask @ zone.js:410
onScheduleTask @ zone.js:301
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.scheduleTask @ zone.js:404
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.scheduleTask @ zone.js:238
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.scheduleMacroTask @ zone.js:261
scheduleMacroTaskWithCurrentZone @ zone.js:1194
(anonymous) @ zone.js:3405
proto.<computed> @ zone.js:1518
(anonymous) @ http.js:1725
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Observable.js.Observable._trySubscribe @ Observable.js:43
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Observable.js.Observable.subscribe @ Observable.js:29
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/tap.js.DoOperator.call @ tap.js:18
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Observable.js.Observable.subscribe @ Observable.js:24
subscribeToResult @ subscribeToResult.js:13
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/mergeMap.js.MergeMapSubscriber._innerSub @ mergeMap.js:74
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/mergeMap.js.MergeMapSubscriber._tryNext @ mergeMap.js:68
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/mergeMap.js.MergeMapSubscriber._next @ mergeMap.js:51
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:53
(anonymous) @ subscribeToArray.js:5
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Observable.js.Observable._trySubscribe @ Observable.js:43
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Observable.js.Observable.subscribe @ Observable.js:29
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/mergeMap.js.MergeMapOperator.call @ mergeMap.js:29
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Observable.js.Observable.subscribe @ Observable.js:24
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/filter.js.FilterOperator.call @ filter.js:15
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Observable.js.Observable.subscribe @ Observable.js:24
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/map.js.MapOperator.call @ map.js:18
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Observable.js.Observable.subscribe @ Observable.js:24
push../src/app/dossier/dossier-physical/dossier-physical.component.ts.DossierPhysicalComponent.ngOnInit @ dossier-physical.component.ts:21
checkAndUpdateDirectiveInline @ core.js:21776
checkAndUpdateNodeInline @ core.js:29989
checkAndUpdateNode @ core.js:29951
debugCheckAndUpdateNode @ core.js:30585
debugCheckDirectivesFn @ core.js:30545
(anonymous) @ dossier-physical.component.html:4
debugUpdateDirectives @ core.js:30537
checkAndUpdateView @ core.js:29933
callViewAction @ core.js:30174
execEmbeddedViewsAction @ core.js:30137
checkAndUpdateView @ core.js:29934
callViewAction @ core.js:30174
execComponentViewsAction @ core.js:30116
checkAndUpdateView @ core.js:29939
callViewAction @ core.js:30174
execEmbeddedViewsAction @ core.js:30137
checkAndUpdateView @ core.js:29934
callViewAction @ core.js:30174
execEmbeddedViewsAction @ core.js:30137
checkAndUpdateView @ core.js:29934
callViewAction @ core.js:30174
execComponentViewsAction @ core.js:30116
checkAndUpdateView @ core.js:29939
callWithDebugContext @ core.js:30803
debugCheckAndUpdateView @ core.js:30505
push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.ViewRef_.detectChanges @ core.js:21365
push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.ApplicationRef.tick @ core.js:27620
(anonymous) @ core.js:27509
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js:391
onInvoke @ core.js:26769
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js:390
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.run @ zone.js:150
push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.NgZone.run @ core.js:26683
next @ core.js:27509
schedulerFn @ core.js:24413
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub @ Subscriber.js:192
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.SafeSubscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:130
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber._next @ Subscriber.js:76
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:53
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subject.js.Subject.next @ Subject.js:47
push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.EventEmitter.emit @ core.js:24397
checkStable @ core.js:26738
onHasTask @ core.js:26782
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.hasTask @ zone.js:443
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate._updateTaskCount @ zone.js:463
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone._updateTaskCount @ zone.js:291
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runTask @ zone.js:212
drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone.js:601
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneTask.invokeTask @ zone.js:502
invokeTask @ zone.js:1693
globalZoneAwareCallback @ zone.js:1719
Show 50 more frames
core.js:7376 ERROR HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 404, statusText: "Not Found", url: "http://localhost:4200/api/patient/%7BpatientUUID%7D/DossierEntry/type/physical", ok: false, …}
```

Comment: `get()` expects 1-2 arguments: https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClient#get You pass 3 arguments. What are you trying to do with the arguments `'pdf'` and `true`?

Comment: I edit the post

Comment: I edit the post.

Comment: Hi Harun, did you see my edited post?

Answer (score 0):

To achieve the desired outcome with new Angular's `HttpClientModule`:

```js
return this.http.get('/api/patient/{patientUUID}/DossierEntry/' + entryID + '/fileData', {
  responseType: 'blob',
  observe: 'response'
})
```

Comment: Hi Sneas. Thank you. I updated the post. Can you have a look on it. What I do wrong. Thank you

Comment: oke, nice had je nog even tijd op naar mijn geupdate post te kijken?

Comment: ik zie dat je je eigen HTTP-service hebt gemaakt. Het serivce gebruikt `this.authService.loginSatus()` om URL te wijzigen. Het nieuwe `HttpClientModule`  biedt een standaardmanier om HTTP-aanvragen te wijzigen. Dit is het gebruiksvoorbeeld: https://medium.com/@ryanchenkie_40935/angular-authentication-using-the-http-client-and-http-interceptors-2f9d1540eb8

Comment: Oke, bedankt voor de link. Ja, ik wil dus nu graag van de hele Invoke method af:  invoke(
    method: 'GET' | 'POST' | 'PUT' | 'DELETE', Maar ik probeer het nu dus ook met de ingebouwde get van HttpClient library. Maar dat werkt dus nog niet.

Comment: Can we go to chat .sneas

Comment: Sorry, now I'm busy. By the error I can see `HttpClient` works fine (at least the request happens), but the server returns 404 because the `parsedRoute = parsedRoute.replace('{patientUUID}', user.profile.participant)` is not happening. You need to properly pass `needsAuthenticateUser` param.

Comment: try to step by step debug the `invoke` method and see why `parsedRoute = parsedRoute.replace('{patientUUID}', user.profile.participant)` is not happening.

Comment: Oke, because the invoke method will  not be called with the new method: Because I dont use that method with the httpCLient library isnt?

Comment: But I want to get rid of the Customised api methods: get, post, and the old way it is using the Invoke method. See the post